# why are these two ways of computing EFA in R not identical?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am confused trying to understand the difference between two ways of executing an EFA in R that I previously assumed to be completely equivalent. First, I make some data up:

```
A <- sin(1:15)
B <- A + sin(2*(1:15))
C <- A + sin(3*(1:15))
D <- 0.5*A + sin(2:16)
E <- D + sin(2*(2:16))
test.data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
```

And then I compute the EFA in two ways:

```
my.efa1 <- factanal(test.data, 2, rotation="promax")
my.efa2 <- factanal(factors=2, covmat=cor(test.data), n.obs=15, rotation="promax")
```

This leads to two outcomes that are almost equal, except that in the first case the correlation between the two factors is negative (-0.641) while in the second case it is positive (0.641).

I used to think that the computation of `my.efa2` was an alternative-but-equivalent form for that of `my.efa1`, but looking at this example it turns out it is not. Why is this the case?

Comment: There has been remarked numerous times on this site - as well as in all FA literature - that the sign of factor or component loadings may be switched with a clear conscience. If you mirror sign in one factor but leave it in the other, their correlation becomes opposite sign.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is about something else. Aren't the two calls to factanal supposed to be equivalent? If so, why the first one leads systematically to a negative correlation while the second one systematically to a positive correlation? It's not that each call gives a random sign for the correlation each time it is executed.

Comment: Algorithms may somewhat differ under different though analytically equivalent specifications. But I believe or admit your question may be off-topic, as it is about R, not factor analysis.